# How can I put the date in a shortcut?

Tags: windows, shortcut, sendto

Im trying to make a SendTo shortcut to a folder whose name changes daily to the current date in the format dd.mm.yyyy . Is there a way to put the current date in the folder path? I have no knowledge of programming

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set mydate=%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%date:~6,4%
echo %mydate%
```

Then you can put `%mydate%` into the folder path

If not get the expected result:

1. ehco `%date%` first   // in my case I got 01/24/18
2. then compose `%mydate%` based on the vaule of `%date%`

such as I got 24.01.2018 with the following

```
set mydate=%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%.20%date:~6,4%
```

I put the following code into a file `test.bat` and used (dbl click) it to:

1. create file `blank.txt` in current folder
2. create new folder with `%mydate%` (`24.01.2018`)
3. create a file `blank.txt` in the new folder

`echo off
 set mydate=%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%.20%date:~6,4%
 mkdir %mydate%
 echo .> dblank.txt
 cd %mydate%
 echo .> dblank.txt`

Comment: Try echo `%date%` first, and compose `%mydate%` based on the value of `%date%` (01/24/18 in my case). In my test I got `24012018` with the code shown.

Comment: if id only understand those numbers id tweak them, could i add the dot separator too?

Comment: I tried, yes,  dot can be added in between, got: 24.01.2018 `set mydate=%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%.20%date:~6,4%`

Comment: thats exactly what i need too. ill try tweaking the numbers

Comment: i figured it out to be %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4% in my case. however, dialog still says that path doesnt exist. should i be saving this code somewhere? ive been using it in cmd

Comment: That works marvelous. But i need to use my %mydate% in the shortcut like this d:\folder1\%mydate%\ can this be achieved?

Comment: Tested, yes, e.g. `echo .> %mydate%\dblank.txt` to create a new file in the new folder directly

Comment: I work with organazing alot of files into folders and its a pain because they keep changing names by current dates. so i figured if i could right click my file and send to> the folders i need based on their path. however when creating a shortcut in windows GUI, in the SendTo folder, to that specific folder, i cant use %mydate% because windows doesnt recognize it as a destination even though my folders are in place and i run the bat file. I dont have admin rights on my work PC if that is an issue

Comment: Just to drop some light. I resolved my issue with the setx command! whatever i set in cmd doesnt reset after cmd session end. Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Very glad of hearing that!